# Questions about Lee's proof of the Closed Subgroup Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading reading Lee's proof of the Closed Subgroup Theorem (Theorem $20.12$) and there is some point in the proof I really do not understand. As the proof is quite long, I'm not going to rewrite the whole proof, just the part I have a problem with. Let me recall the setting:

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra, $\mathfrak h \subseteq \mathfrak g$ a subspace and $\mathfrak b$ the complementary to $\mathfrak h$ in $\mathfrak g$ (so that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak h \oplus \mathfrak b$). We know that there is a neighborhood $U_0$ of $0$ in $\mathfrak g$ such that $\exp|_{U_0}$ is a diffeomorphism and we can show that the map
$$\Phi: \mathfrak h \oplus \mathfrak b \to G : (X, Y) \mapsto \exp X\cdot \exp Y$$
is a diffeomorphism in some neighborhood $\widetilde{U}_0$ of $(0,0)$. Now the author says that we can choose a countable neighboorhood basis $(U_i)_i$ for $\mathfrak g$ at $0$ such that the $U_i$'s consist of coodinate balls whose radii approach zero (**1. , here is my first question**). After we set $V_i = \exp (U_i)$ and $\widetilde U_i = \Phi^{-1}(V_i)$ which are neighborhood bases for $G$ at $0$ and $\mathfrak h \oplus \mathfrak b$ at $(0,0)$ respectively (**2., here is my second question**). By discarding finitely many terms at the beginning of the sequence, we may assume that $U_i \subseteq U_0$ and $\widetilde U_i \subseteq \widetilde U_0$ for each (**this is obvious if we assume that 1. is true**). Finally, we consider $(X_i, Y_i) \in \widetilde{U}_i$ for each $i$ and as $\widetilde{U}_i$ is a neighborhood basis, $Y_i \to 0$ for $i \to \infty$ (**3., here is my last question**).

Now let met detail my questions:

1. if I understand the sentence correctly, the sequence $(U_i)_i$ should generate every open of $\mathfrak g$ passing through $0$. How is it possible that the radius of $U_i$ goes to zero as the $U_i$'s should also generate the very big open sets of $\mathfrak g$ passing through $0$ ?
2. I do not see why it should be bases as, at that point, we did not suppose $U_i \subseteq U_0$ so that $\exp$ and $\Phi$ are not diffeomorphisms.
3. I really do not understand this point.. Can we deduce that the radii of $\widetilde U_i$ goes to zero if it is the case for $U_i$ ?

I hope this question is clear, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your questions actually concern general topology, they are not really related to manifolds or Lie groups.

1. The fact that $\{U_i\}$ is a neighborhood basis for $0$ by definition means that any neighborhood of $0$ contains one of the sets $U_i$. Otherwise put, any open subset that contains $0$ has to contain one of the $U_i$. This is different from the notion of a basis for the topology.
2. By construction, the neighborhood basis consist of nested sets, so you can assume that $U_j\subset U_i$ for $j>i$. This means that dropping the first $N$ sets $U_i$, one still has a neighborhood basis. Since one $U_{i_0}$ is contained in $U_0$, you can assume without loss of generality that they all are.
3. In a Hausdorff space, the intersection of all elements of any neighborhood basis of a point $x$ consists of the point $x$ only. By construction $Y_j\in U_i$ for any $j\geq i$. This readily implies convergence by definition.